# Laravel @ SSL after registration or login, user redirected to site/s

Tags: php, laravel, .htaccess, ssl, laravel-5

Very strange issue. Once I install Lets Encrypt SSL.

**in config/app** *set URL* as: https://mywebsite

**in layout.blade.view** set all *as secure_asset* (to load over httpS)

If I turn off SSL , then everything is OK

Here are my .htaccess in root :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index\.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)index.php$ /$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
```

And here is my .htaccess in public folder

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Problem is, when user is registered on website or logged in, then instead of redirecting to proper URL, user is redirected to mysite.com/s

If I turn OFF SSL, then everything is OK, so it means, that code is 100% working and fine.. am I right?

Thnx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOlution found:
I clear a cache, and this problem dissapeared

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.abc.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.abcds.com/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^abc.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.abcds.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```